# Getting XML Error when saving blogger template

Tags: xml, templates, blogger

I am getting the below mentioned error, when i try to use the [xml code from here.](http://pastebin.com/QFa0SvY8)

The template is not mine, but a friend's. I am trying to use the same for my blog.

Please let me know what is the error.

Your template could not be parsed as it is not well-formed. Please make sure all XML elements are closed properly.
XML error message: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked to is not a vaild xml template.Can you not download the template from the same source your friend did ?

If Not - Go to your friends blog > *Design page* > *Edit html page* > tick the *Expand widget template* box.

Copy all the code.

Back to your blog > *Design page* > *Edit html page* > tick the *Expand widget template* box.

Replace your template code with the code from your friends blog and save.

It's vital you tick the expand widget templates box..

You can look for a similar template - http://www.bestbloggertemplates.net - Good luck.